# Eclipse and qmake

Tags: eclipse, qt

This is my first message on this forum… so hello at all..

I have to make c++ project with Eclipse IDE and using QT library… and I want to integrate QT library…
So I have downloaded Eclipse and QT version 5.1.0, included the library and all work…My problem born when I try to integrate qmake in eclipse for using moc compiler… I followed this procedure www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_use_Eclipse_with_Qt4_in_10_steps.. but doesn't work…

Could someone help me?
Thanks

Sorry. I try to explain better the problem...
After installing eclipse with O.S. windows I have created a new project:

1) File->new->c++ Project (inserted the project name) and selected MinGW GCC as toolchains and debug and release as configurations

2)Project->Properties-> C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Includes .. I included the path of may Qt library

3)Project->Properties-> C/C++ Build->Settings->MinGW C++ Linker-> LIbraries I included the link to the libraries.

4)I have created my file project called main.cpp and the header and cpp for my class (testclass1.h testclass1.cpp)

5) My class is a deriverd class of QObject and since I have to use signal and slot I need of Q_OBJECT macro.

6) Run->External ToolsConfigrations I created two new Programs.

```
 .Name:Qmake
 .Location .../bin/qmake

 .Name:QtAssistant
 .Location .../bin/assistant
```

7)Created a new target in my "Make target"
        Target Name: qmake
        Make Target: myQtProj.pro 
        Build Command: qmake

```
    Target Name: all
    Make Target: all
    Build Command: default (make)
```

8) when I run qmake I have this error: undefined reference to `vtable for testclass1..I thinks that this depends on the macro Q_OBJECT.. I expect that running qmake the moc compiler is called so I should have in testclass1.cpp the macro Q_OBJECT "expanded"..

At the moment I solved the problem in this manner(from command line I called):
qmake -project (create myproject.pro)
qmake (create a makefile)
mingw32-make that create moc_testclass1.cpp...
So I copy the content of moc_testclass1.cpp in my testclass1... and I can build the project and all work. But this is not and automated way..

I hope to be more clear in my description.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will need to provide more information regarding what doesn't work. What kind of error messages are you getting? Do you have any stacktraces? Edit your question with this information, if not I'm afraid its impossible to help you and the question will be closed.

Comment: Ok sorry.. I try to explain better..

Comment: I recommend you not to develop qt in eclipse. It's better to use QtCreator which fully supports Qt and has useful tools and features. Qt Eclipse integration has been stopped and i doubt if new versions of Qt support Eclipse.

Comment: Ok.. I know Qt creator but I have to use eclipse because is a requirement of the project I'm working on..Is there any solution?